# SQL MAX(ID) Возвращает пустой массив если строк нет

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно получить максимальный id в таблице, но в таблице может не оказаться записей, по какой-то причине sql запрос ниже возвращает массив с 1 пустым элементом:

```
'SELECT MAX(id) FROM `history`'
```

Код:

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT MAX(id) FROM `history`');
$test = $res->fetch_row();
var_dump($test);
```

Вывод:

```
array(1) {  [0]=>  NULL }
```

И получается что стандартная проверка $res->num_rows > 0 не корректна, т.к. num_rows = 1, просто массив пустой.

Как можно коротко проверить вернул ли что-то запрос ?

Comment: Он возвращает не массив, а результат. Результат заключается в том, что записей нет, поэтому максимальный индекс - `NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), тогда в случае, если в таблице 0 элементов, вернёт 1 элемент со значением 0:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) FROM `history`
```

Или [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) FROM `history`
```

Если нужно, чтоб в случае отсутствия записей вернулось именно 0 строк, то:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM `history` HAVING MAX(id) is not null
```

Comment: по моему вы усложняете. `$test = (int) $res->fetch_row()[0];`

Comment: ArchDemon  эта конструкция с какой версии php работает ? Я получаю ошибку syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: @LorDo версия php тут не причем. Это же mysql... Скорее всего нужно назначить alias, типа такого `SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0) as myvalue FROM \`history\`` и обращаться в php к полю `myvalue` или как назовете... ну или что-то в синтаксисе пхп накосячили

Comment: @LorDo ой, вру конечно.... `$res->fetch_row()[0];` - так можно начиная с 5.4..... версии >= 5.3  надо в начале извлечь `$res->fetch_row();` в отдельную переменную, а потом только у нее брать по индексу